# Problem with reinstantiating map objects HERE Maps

Tags: javascript, here-api, heremaps

I have a draggable marker that is created with an address serach and I need do create a circle around the marker, delete the circle whenever I move the marker and create another circle when I stop moving the marker. The problem is: When I do only one search, it works without a single problem, when I search a second time, it creates a new circle where the new marker is and after I try to move the marker or the map, other 2 circles are created out of nowhere, and if I move the marker after the 2 additional circles are created, these 2 circles goes to the start coordinate of the first marker (which is now deleted) and to the final coordinte of the same first marker.
How can I delete these circles forever? I've tried group.removeObject, group.removeAll as well as delete circle, circle = null and circle = undefined, none of these have worked.
There's also an error when I try to move the map or the marker after the second search.

```
Uncaught IllegalOperationError: H.map.Group#removeObject object not found
```

```
function addDraggableMarker(map, behavior) {
  group.removeAll();

  let marker = new H.map.Marker(
    { lat: latit, lng: longi },
    {
      volatility: true,
    }
  );
  marker.draggable = true;
  group.addObject(marker);
  circle = new H.map.Circle({ lat: lati, lng: long }, raioF);
  group.addObject(circle);

  map.addEventListener(
    "dragstart",
    function (ev) {
      group.removeObject(circle);
      let target = ev.target,
        pointer = ev.currentPointer;
      if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
        let targetPosition = map.geoToScreen(target.getGeometry());
        target["offset"] = new H.math.Point(
          pointer.viewportX - targetPosition.x,
          pointer.viewportY - targetPosition.y
        );
        behavior.disable();
      }
    },
    false
  );

  map.addEventListener(
    "dragend",
    function (ev) {
      let target = ev.target;
      if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
        behavior.enable();
        latit = marker.b.lat;
        longi = marker.b.lng;
      }
      circle = new H.map.Circle({ lat: lati, lng: long }, raioF);
      group.addObject(circle);
    },
    false
  );

  map.addEventListener(
    "drag",
    function (ev) {
      let target = ev.target,
        pointer = ev.currentPointer;
      if (target instanceof H.map.Marker) {
        target.setGeometry(
          map.screenToGeo(
            pointer.viewportX - target["offset"].x,
            pointer.viewportY - target["offset"].y
          )
        );
      }
    },
    false
  );
}
```